Drawing a 2D surface specified by line element $ds^2=dr^2$
This is the line element for Euclidean space in spherical coordinates
$$ds^2=dr^2+r^2d\theta^2+r^2\sin^2\theta d\phi^2$$
One can obtain any 2D surface by making one of the variables $r$, $\theta$, $\phi$ constant. For example, if I fix $r=R$ where $R$ is some constant, the above line element becomes $ds^2=R^2d\theta^2+R^2\sin^2\theta d\phi^2$. This is the line element for surface of a sphere of radius $R$.
I wonder what happens if I fix $\theta=0$. The line element becomes $ds^2=dr^2$. I am not sure what kind of 2D surface can be described by this line element. Any ideas?

Start with forgetting the line elements and think geometrically what "object" you specify with $\theta=0.$ Hint: this object does not have  a defined azimuth $\phi,.$

@KurtG. A point located at origin maybe?

This coordinate system fails when $\theta=0,\pi$, i.e., along the $z$-axis.

@TedShifrin According to Wikipedia, it seems like $\theta$ can take values from $0$ to $\pi$ inclusive. Is it wrong?

Yes, it’s wrong. The fact that the metric collapses as it does indicates that $\theta$ cannot equal $0,\pi$. You can also see that when $\theta=0,\pi$, all values of $\varphi$ give the same point. Similarly, whether Wiki says so or not, you must have $r>0$.

The restrictions $r > 0, 0 < \theta < \pi, 0 \le \phi < 2\pi$ are necessary to avoid having multiple coordinates for the same point. This is in itself not a major problem, so mostly they can be dropped. But the restrictions $r \ne 0, \theta \ne k\pi$ are required for the coordinate system to be non-singular. Where the coordinate system is not singular, holding one of the coordinates constant yields a 2D "level surface". But  you get a 1D "level curve" for $\theta$ where it is singular ($\theta = k\pi$), and a 0D "level point" for $r$ where it is singular ($r=0$) .
